# CodeIgniter 3.1.9 - Call to undefined method stdClass::base_url()

Tags: codeigniter

My controller code is :

```
  class Tconfig extends CI_Controller {
  public $config;

  public function __construct($schoolId = 1) {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->model('Tconfig_model');
    $this->config = $this->Tconfig_model->load_config($schoolId);
  }

  public function config() {
    $data['config'] = $this->config;
    $this->load->view('templates/user_header', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/user_menu', $data);
//    printf("%s", base_url());
    //$this->load->view('config', $data);
    //$this->load_view('templates/user_footer', $data);
  }

}
```

**I have autoloaded url_helper**

At this point, I am just trying to load a HTML file which includes a call to base_url()
The exact line where this function is called is :

```
<link href=<?php echo base_url();?>"assets/bootstrap337/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

When I run this code through a debugger, I get this

[image: Debugger output]

What I cannot figure out is why I get a call to an undefined method **stdClass::base_url()** in **url_helper.php**

I am pretty sure that it's something very obvious, but it's been a long day .. TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is - you overwrite the CI intern Variable `config` with your own - you can avoid this by renaming your variable

something like the following should work

```
class Tconfig extends CI_Controller 
{
    public $tcConfig;

    public function __construct($schoolId = 1) 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('Tconfig_model');
        $this->tcConfig = $this->Tconfig_model->load_config($schoolId);
    }

    public function config() 
    {
        $data['config'] = $this->tcConfig;
        $this->load->view('templates/user_header', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/user_menu', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Elementary, my dear Watson!  The pricelessness of a code review. As I said, it had been a long day.  Thank you once again

Answer (score 2):

You have to load url helper in `application->Config->autoload.php`  file


Like this:-

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

OR


Add this in construct function in controller

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Answer (score 0):

use this in your header file.

```
<script>
 var base_url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>';
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

check whether you defined your base url in your config.php file. If not, define it like-

```
$config['base_url'] = 'your-base-url';
```

in your config.php file in application/config folder.